# Installing systemc SCV library on x86-64 machine

Tags: systemc

When I tried to install the SCV library, I came accross with the following problem:

"checking build system type... Invalid configuration `x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu': machine` x86_64-unknown' not recognized "

I copied the 'config.guess' and 'config.sub' from /usr/share/libtool/config to overwrite the existing 'config.guess' and 'config.sub' of SCV. Then I can configure further, but new problem is:

**"configure: error: Target CPU type not supported: "x86_64""**

I think SCV should support x86_64 target, so how can I solve this problem?
Great thanks!
Kun

Answer (score 0):

The SCV does not support x86_64 in its original configuration. Please see the patch at http://thawedoutnow.blogspot.tw/2013/02/scv-for-x8664-linux-patch.html. Your system might also need GNU automake, autoconf, m4, and some development tools to generate the new `configure` file.

Another one is directly modifying the `configure` file. Please see http://boyangdu.wordpress.com/2011/11/13/systemc-setup-on-f16-x86_64/ for details